# Using jQuery Check if table th has an attribute value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to display content on the window resize and load. After that clicking `table th` attribute is equal to the given value. I don't know where I am doing wrong but I am unable to get the result.

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(e) {
  var $theWindowSize = $(this).width();
  if ($theWindowSize < 768) {
    alert($theWindowSize);
    if ($('table th').attr('id') == 'basic-tab') {
      $('table th#basic-tab').on('click', function(e) {
        alert('basic');
        $('table .basic-content').css('display', 'block');
      });
    } else if ($('table th').attr('id') == 'standard-tab') {
      $('table th#standard-tab').on('click', function(e) {
        alert('standard');
        $('table .standard-content').css('display', 'block');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.basic-content,
.standard-content {
  dispaly: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="basic-tab">Tab1</th>
    <th id="standard-tab">Tab2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="basic-content">
    <td>Basic Content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="standard-content">
    <td>Standard Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML too?

Comment: i think you need to do :- `$('table .content').css('display','block');`

Comment: please check now code updated

Comment: please read the question and understand properly what is required @User863

Comment: do on click event first then do some condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On click of `th` get the `id`, split it and get first part, and then check which `tr` contain `class` started from this `string` and contain `content` as well. Apply CSS on that

Working snippet:-

```js
$('table th').on('click',function(e){
  var thId = $(this).attr('id');
  var compare = thId.split('-')[0];
  $('tr').each(function(){
      if($(this).attr('class') != undefined){
        $(this).css('display','none');
      }
  });
  $('tr[class*='+compare+'-content]').css('display','block');
});
```

```css
.basic-content,.standard-content{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="basic-tab">Tab1</th>
    <th id="standard-tab">Tab2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="basic-content">
    <td>Basic Content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="standard-content">
    <td>Standard Content</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Note:- Added `content` in code `$('tr[class*='+compare+'-content]')` as per your HTML. if you need to add CSS to all who contains `basic` or `standered` in there class then remove `content` from code and make it  `$('tr[class*='+compare+'-]')`.

Comment: Awsome Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$(".th") is returning only first element so let's try seperately:

```
$(".th").eq(n)
```

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(e) {
  var $theWindowSize = $(this).width();
  if ($theWindowSize < 768) {
    alert($theWindowSize);
    if ($('table th').eq(0).attr('id') === 'basic-tab') {
      $("body").on('click','table th#basic-tab', function(e) {
        alert('basic');
        $('table .basic-content').css('display', 'block');
      });
    } if ($('table th').eq(1).attr('id') === 'standard-tab') {
      $('body').on('click','table th#standard-tab',function(e) {
        alert('standard');
        $('table .standard-content').css('display', 'block');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.basic-content,
.standard-content {
  dispaly: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="basic-tab">
      Tab1
    </th>
    <th id="standard-tab">
      Tab2
    </th>
  </tr><tr>
  <div class="basic-content">
    <td>Basic Content</td></div>
      <div class="standard-content">
        <td>Standard Content</td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```